# Connecting a Mixer to iPad Pro

Tags: ipad

I would like to know if I can connect and use a Behringer Xenyx 1002FX mixer, with an C-1 (Behringer) condensor mic connected, to my iPad for recording with Garageband or Audacity.

Answer (score 1):

I just googled your mixer and it appears that this device doesn't have a USB-Interface to get a digital signal of the mixer's output.

You need a digital audio interface like the Behringer U-Phoria UMC204HD. You can then plug your mixer into the audio interface and connect the audio interface to the iPad Pro using a USB-Adapter.